# How do I fix jQuery("#contact_form").validate is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

We are using WordPress divi theme on our website and we have a contact form that uses [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

custom.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var contactForm = jQuery("#contact_form");

    contactForm.validate({
        rules: {
            full_name: {required:true, maxlength:100},
            email: {required:true, validateEmail: true},
            phone_number: {required:true}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var fullName = jQuery('#full_name').val();
            var email = jQuery('#email').val();
            var phoneNumber = jQuery('#phone_number').val();
            var contactFormUrl = contactForm.attr('action');

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: contactFormUrl,
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    fullname: fullName,
                    email: email,
                    phonenumber: phoneNumber
                }
            }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log("Success");
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Fail")
            });

        }
    });

});
```

We minify our `custom.js` into `custom.min.js` . When I view our website on console this is what I see:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.validate is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.min.js?ver=1:1)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

This is the order of the scripts loaded into the DOM:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' async='async' src='/divi-child/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js?ver=1'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' defer='defer' src='/divi-child/scripts/v3/custom.min.js?ver=1'></script>
```

Do you know how can to solve it? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is jQuery validate loaded? is `custom.min.js` loaded before it?

Comment: Hi. `custom.min.js` is loaded after `jquery.validate.min.js` is included

Comment: Add all js includes to see if there's an interference between them

Comment: try to disable async loading.

Comment: @Roy I have updated my question. jQuery lib is included

Comment: @MarkBaijens I'll try your suggestion

Comment: Check this link - https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/343

Comment: try putting validate.min.js before jquery.

Comment: @iSahilSharma Hi my error is not a `.validator` function but `.validate`

Comment: Try after removing "async" and "defer" in script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as follow:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/divi-child/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/divi-child/scripts/v3/custom.min.js?ver=1'></script>
```

Also can you provide scripts folder content here? because there is 'v3' is used in cutom.min.js but not for other two js's.

Comment: Thank you for this. `v3` is just a folder name. The other 2 `js` files don't need the v3 folder